# lua - want to call a function in main.lua from another module

Tags: function, module, lua

I want a to call a function that is defined in main.lua from a module that is required (included) in main.lua. What's the best/cleanest way to do this?

Edit:

I eventually went down the dispatch event route. That seems to be a neat way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Make it available in the global table. For example:

```lua
--main.lua
require "myModule"

myModule.someFunc()

function mainFunc(...)
    --...
end

--myModule.lua
module(myModule)

mainFunc(parameters)
```

As long as the module doesn't define the same variable name locally (and if it does, you can use `_G.mainFunc` to get it), you should be fine.

Comment: Note that using global namespace in this manner is a bad programming practice.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid the global namespace if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options as far as I can see:

1. Define the function A first, then `require()` the module, and call function A there.
2. `require()` the module first, and have the module define a function B that calls the function A in your main file. Call function B whenever you are ready to call it (i.e. function A is defined) in your main file.

The latter seems cleaner, but that would be a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Move that function to a separate module. This is the cleanest way.

Otherwise, use a global variable to store that function.